# How to enumerate network computers from command line?

Tags: networking, command-line-interface, powershell, hostname

I am on Windows XP and would like to enumerate the computers that exist on my network from a command line.  I would like to enumerate them such that I can use the host names in another command, pslist .  I suspect that I can use PowerShell and the "net view" command to do this, but can't iron out the specifics.

Comment: Are these domain or standalone computers?

Comment: Can they be read from Active Directory?  I have a PS script that gets the list from AD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting in "net view" is pretty crappy for parsing since it displays NetBIOS names and they *can* contain spaces. (Why anyone would actually use spaces is beyond me, though...)

If you're sure your computer names don't have spaces, do:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims= " %%i in (`net view ^| find "\\"`) do echo %%i
```

Obviously, substitute a call to another batch file or a command for the "echo".

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to enumerate systems; in fact I have a whole [wiki page](http://quux.wiki.zoho.com/Enumerate-Computers.html) devoted to just this.

But one pretty nice way is with [nbtscan](http://unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.html), which will give you a list like this:

```
C:\> nbtscan 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.3     MTNDEW\WINDEV               SHARING DC
192.168.1.5     MTNDEW\TESTING
192.168.1.9     MTNDEW\WIZ                  SHARING U=STEVE
192.168.1.99    MTNDEW\XPDEV                SHARING
```